# R Shiny basic questions

Tags: r, shiny

I'm getting two warnings that I do not exactly understand:

```
Warning in if (file == "") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Warning: Error in file: invalid 'description' argument
  166: file
  165: parse
  163: renderPlot [...app.R#51]
  161: func
  121: drawPlot
  107: <reactive:plotObj>
   91: drawReactive
   78: origRenderFunc
   77: output$Minimum_Rates
    1: runApp
```

As a somewhat beginner to R and Shiny, I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. Chances are there are tons of things wrong with this program, but if anyone could give me a hand on these two current errors, that would be awesome. Here's my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(rstudioapi)

ui <- fluidPage(


  # Give the page a title
  titlePanel("Rate Analysis"),

  # Generate a row with a sidebar
  sidebarLayout(      

    # Define the sidebar with one input
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("ProductType","Product Type: (Choose One)",choices=c("t","r")),
      selectInput("inSelect","Carrier: (Choose One)",choices=unique(c(t_rates_names,r_rates_names))),
      selectInput("Category","Category: (Choose One)",choices=c("Age","Term","Band","Class","Gender")),
      sliderInput("discount","% Discount:",min=0,max=100,value=0),
      width=3
    ),

    # Create a spot for the barplot
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("Minimum_Rates")  
    )

  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    req(input$ProductType)
    x<-sym(input$ProductType)
    updateSelectInput(session,"inSelect",label=paste("test"),choices=eval(parse(text=paste0(x,"_rates_names"))))
  })

  output$Minimum_Rates<-renderPlot({
    req(input$inSelect)
    req(input$Category)
    req(input$discount)
    req(input$ProductType)
    carrier<-(input$inSelect)
    carrier<-eval(parse(text=carrier))
    category<-sym(input$Category)
    discount<-input$discount
    string_name=deparse(substitute(carrier))
    fee_name=eval(parse(paste0(substr(string_name,1,nchar(string_name)-6),"_fees")))
    carrier<-discountRatesAndFindNewPrems(carrier,discount/100,fee_name)
    tMinTable<-removeTheseRatesAndFindMinimumRates(t_list_rates)
    if(as_string(input$ProductType)=="t"){
      carrier %<%
        createRatesComparedToTMin(carrier) %<%
        original_percent_higher<-Percent_Higher %<%
        findRatesFromPrems(carrier,fee_name) %<%
        original_rates<-`Rates per Thousand` %<%
        group_by(!!!category) %>%
        summarise(Current_Comparison=sum(original_percent_higher),Hypothetical_Comparison=sum(New_Percent_Higher)) %>%
        ggplot(aes_string(input$category,"Current_Comparison"))+geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") + geom_text(aes(label=scales::percent(Current_Comparison)),size=3.2,vjust=-0.5,position=position_dodge(width=1))
    }
    else{
      rMinTable<-removeTheseRatesAndFindMinimumRates(r_list_rates)
      carrier$Percent_Higher<-original_percent_higher
      carrier<-createNewRatesComparedToRMin(carrier)
      carrier%>%
        group_by(!!!category) %>%
        summarise(Current_Comparison=sum(original_percent_higher),Hypothetical_Comparison=sum(New_Percent_Higher))
        ggplot(aes_string(input$Category,"Current_Comparison"))+geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") + geom_text(aes(label=scales::percent(Current_Comparison)),size=3.2,vjust=-0.5,position=position_dodge(width=1))  
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Another question I have is what kind of data type are the selections? Are they basically whatever type that I enter in the "choices parameter? So if my choices are all string, then why do I need to convert them to symbol?

Edit: I added a print(string_name) after the     string_name=deparse(substitute(carrier)) line, and it looks like print(string_name) is printing the entire df while I meant to get the name of the df to be string_name. I think I have some misunderstandings about what the "carrier" data type should be. Anyone know?

Comment: Your first warning is the same as doing `x <- "foo"; if ( x == c("bar", "baz")) { }` - you're testing an `if` against multiple conditions, whereas it's expecting a test against one condition.

Comment: A good question on SO is small, self contained and (usually) asks about a single issue. I recommend creating a very small shiny app which replicates your issue. As it is, other people can't use your code as there are a lot of functions which we don't have access too.

Comment: I thought input$ProductType would only be one item at a time? Or is input a vector?

Comment: Are you sure that's what's generating the error?

Comment: I agree with SymbolixAU. You are using multiple conditions in `if` statement. Instead try `ifelse`. That will allow you to test multiple conditions.